# Codeigniter - Passing multiple parameters

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to pass multiple parameters to my model from my controller. It seems that the `$scholId` that I am trying to pass won't go through to the model after I submit the form. However, the `$userId` goes through to the database just fine. Is there something wrong with `$this->uri->segment(4)` that won't pass through correctly?

```
function apply() 
{
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $scholId = $this->uri->segment(4);

    $userId = '2'; //User query -> this will be taken from session

    $this->data['scholarship'] = $this->scholarship_model->getScholarship($scholId);
    $this->data['title'] = "Apply";

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('essay', 'Essay', 'required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
    {
        $this->load->view('templates/header', $this->data);
        $this->load->view('student/page_head', $this->data);
        $this->load->view('student/form', $this->data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer', $this->data);
    }else{
        // Validation passes
        $this->users_model->applySchol($userId,$scholId);
        redirect('/scholarships');
    }
}
```

Comment: when you submit the form segment will not have any value

Comment: can you do var_dump($schoId) before submitting and post it here?

Comment: Make sure you're getting the right segment. Controller is 1, function is 2 etc. Don't count the base url (sort of obvious I suppose) Can you show an example URL that isn't working? Do what mamdouh said dump it out, if it isn't returning what you think or anything try changing it to 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to check up the segment whether it exists or not before passing it Like:

```
if ($this->uri->segment(4) === FALSE)
{
    $schoId = 0; //or anything else so that you know that does not exists
}
else
{
    $schoID= $this->uri->segment(4);
}
```

or simply:

```
$product_id = $this->uri->segment(4, 0);
//which will return 0 if it doesn't exists.
```